# Promise.allSettled stuck forever

Tags: javascript

I use `Promise.allSettled` to fetch websites in batch fashion. It works fine if I limit size of website list to `10` but it become stuck as soon as I increase it to `1000`.

This is weird and never happened to me. I've waited for three days until the script finish but it's still stuck at the first `1000` items.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const lineReader = require('line-by-line');

const reader = new lineReader("./all.json");

let lines = [];
const limit = 1000;

let successCount = 0;

reader.on('line', async (line) => {
    line = JSON.parse(line);

    lines.push(line);

    if (lines.length === limit) {
        reader.pause();

        let promises = [];

        for (const line of lines) {
            promises.push(rp(line.website))
        }
    
        await Promise.allSettled(promises);

        successCount++
        console.log(`Success Count is ${successCount}`);

        lines = [];

        reader.resume();
    }
});
```

The `data.json` file has website list under following format,

```
{ website: "https://www.google.com" }
{ website: "https://www.bing.com" }
{ website: "https://www.microsoft.com" }
```

You can reproduce the behavior by duplicating a line like `{ website: "https://www.google.com" }` 2000 times.

Comment: @trincot No. It's 1000 concurrent requests and it's stuck forever. These requests goes for diff websites not a one but I found that you can reproduce the behavior by duplicating a line like `{website: "https://www.google.com"}` 2000 times

Comment: Would the following also hang forever? You have more than `Promise.allSettled` going one in your code `Promise.allSettled(Array.from({length: 2000}, () => 'https://www.google.com').map(x => fetch(x))).then(() => console.log('done'))`

Comment: @geoffrey Yours works but I have no idea what's wrong with my code. I have shorten the code now and edited the question. Do you see anything wrong with that?

Comment: @geoffrey I use line-by-line package to read thru lines and push to the Lines array. Once the Lines array hit  the limit I specified the line-by-line reader become paused and I then loop over each item on Lines array and perform fetch request then push to `promises` array and then I invoke `Promise.allSettled` for the array containing promises.

Comment: Can you try with `const promises = lines.map((line, i) => rp(line.website).then(r => console.log(i+' fulflilled'), e => console.log(i+' rejected', e)));`? That should give you some insight into where it's stopping

Comment: @Bergi I did and there were some `500` error codes, but this should not stuck `Promise.allSettled` because `Promise.allSettled`'s design is to skip these errors unlike `Promise.all` which stop at errors.

Comment: @Bergi By the way, yours didn't stuck the execution.

Comment: @jeffbRTC The more important question is whether there were 1000 responses, or whether `rp` timed out(?) without settling the promise(!?).

Comment: Also try `reader.on('error', console.error)`. And there's a design mistake with your reader: the last batch will never be sent if its size doesn't hit exactly the limit. You still will need to listen for the `end` event and then send the requests for the last array of `lines`.

Comment: @Bergi I ran your code again and it become stuck at `220 rejected RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOU`

Comment: This means you probably can't/shouldn't use 1000 parallel connections. But yeah, still the `Promise.allSettled` should complete and continue the reader - if you say the other 780 request promises are neither fulfilled nor rejected after one timed out, that sounds like a serious bug in that library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230187/discussion-between-jeffbrtc-and-bergi).

Comment: @Bergi Seems there is some bug in lib. Found an another question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56320940/14659574

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to wrap up my promise with a promise that timeout after certain period.

Here is the function that provides the ability timeout the promise,

```
const withTimeout = (millis, promise) => {
    const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        setTimeout(
            () => reject(`Timed out after ${millis} ms.`),
            millis));
    return Promise.race([
        promise,
        timeout
    ]);
};
```

You can use it like below,

```
await Promise.allSettled([
   withTimeout(5000, rp("https://www.google.com"),
   withTimeout(5000, rp("https://www.bing.com"),
]));
```

I know you can specify a timeout in the request-promise options, but for some reason it didn't work for me, but I noticed certain improvements when I added it.

Comment: Perfect answer.